# Add storyboard for Validation.ErrorTemplate in WPF

Tags: wpf, validation, storyboard

I'm trying to animate a fade-in and fade-out of my `ErrorTemplates` to not scare my users too much by occurring too quickly. The thing I came up with is the below code (which does not work). I guess the `ErrorTemplate` does not have access to the attached `Validation.HasError` property on the control. I also tried a `DataTrigger` bound to `Validation.HasError` on `self`, but that doesn't work either.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="true"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                         RepeatBehavior="3x"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="0.6" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Border x:Name="border"
            BorderBrush="Red"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="2"
            Opacity="0.0">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Margin="-1" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

-- UPDATE
I found out that another less generic but nice way is to restyle controls by implementing ValidationStates visual state group using the visual statemanager. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with the `DataTrigger`.

But you need to bind to the adorner's `AdornedElement` `Validation.HasError` property with:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=adorner, 
                             Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.HasError)}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation AutoReverse="true"
                                Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                RepeatBehavior="3x"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                To="0.6" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2"
        Opacity="0.0">
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Margin="-1" x:Name="adorner" />
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```